# How can I use 'time.After' and 'default' in Golang?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to understand a simple code of Golang routines:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func sleep(seconds int, endSignal chan<- bool) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    endSignal <- true
}

func main() {
    endSignal := make(chan bool, 1)
    go sleep(3, endSignal)
    var end bool

    for !end {
        select {
        case end = <-endSignal:
            fmt.Println("The end!")
        case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("There's no more time to this. Exiting!")
            end = true
        }
    }

}
```

That's fine, but Why I cannot use a simple default in this "select" block? Something like this:

```
for !end {
    select {
    case end = <-endSignal:
        fmt.Println("The end.")
    case <-time.After(4 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("There's no more time to this. Exiting!")
        end = true
    default:
        fmt.Println("No end signal received.")
    }
}
```

It gets this output:

```
❯ go run goroutines-timeout.go
No end signal received!
No end signal received!
No end signal received!
No end signal received!
...
The end!
```

And I can't understand why.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Each time you execute `time.After(4 * time.Second)` you create a new timer channel. There's no way the `select` statement can remember the channel it selected on in the previous iteration. You've also taken what was an asynchronous operation and turned it into a busy loop, defeating the purpose of the `select` statement.

All you need is a a simple select around the two channels you're interested in. It doesn't need to loop at all.

```
select {
case <-endSignal:
    fmt.Println("The end!")
case <-time.After(4 * time.Second):
    fmt.Println("There's no more time to this. Exiting!")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jb4EE8e6cw

If you really want to poll multiple times, make the timer outside of the for loop, so that the same one is checked each iteration

```
timeout := time.After(5 * time.Second)
pollInt := time.Second

for {
    select {
    case <-endSignal:
        fmt.Println("The end!")
        return
    case <-timeout:
        fmt.Println("There's no more time to this. Exiting!")
        return
    default:
        fmt.Println("still waiting")
    }
    time.Sleep(pollInt)
}
```

Comment: regarding the last part (for/select), is that really the way to go? I mean, `time.Sleep` is blocking, so any "endSignal" arriving during that period will not be processed immediately for example.

Comment: @MrFuppes: that is correct, if you want to act on `endSignal` immediately, you would use `time.After` like in the first example.

Comment: Or you add a second timer that fires every `pollInt` and add it to the `select` instead of the `default` statement. Then the `select` waits until it is 'time to poll' and can abort immediately on `endSignal`